# To delete an entire linked list in java which I have created

Tags: java, singly-linked-list

I want to delete an entire list which I have created in java(note: I am not using internal list in java.util). I have assigned head to null but my question is will the java garbage collector handle the list which has no head or should I delete every node(I mean setting every node to null) which will be handled by java garbage collector? Following is my code, please let me know which one is ok although both works but I would still like to know. Thanks in advance.

```
//first code
public void deleteList()
{
    Node n = head;
    Node n1;
    head = null;
    System.out.println("Deleting list");
    while(n != null)
    {
        n1 = n;
        n = n.next;
        n1 = null;
    }
    n1 = n;
    n1 = null;
    System.out.println("List deleted");
}
```

```
//second code
public void deleteList()
{
    head = null;
}
```

Comment: Both work, but there may be a performance benefit if the first one makes the garbage collector's job easier; for example the [JDK implementation](https://hg.openjdk.java.net/jdk8/jdk8/jdk/file/tip/src/share/classes/java/util/LinkedList.java#l444) of `LinkedList.clear` does set all the references to `null`, with the comment: *"Clearing all of the links between nodes is "unnecessary", but: - helps a generational GC if the discarded nodes inhabit more than one generation - is sure to free memory even if there is a reachable Iterator"*.

Comment: That said, note that your first version *does not actually set any of the references to null* - it sets the local variable `n1` to null, which is not the same at all.

Comment: I don't understand how this is a question. The second version works correctly, is as simple as possible, and specifically takes advantage of the language feature available to you (garbage collection). Why would you even consider doing anything else?

Comment: @KarlKnechtel You might consider doing it explicitly for performance reasons; see my comment about the JDK implementation.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

The Garbage Collector will destroy an object only when the particular object doesn't have any linked internal dependency to other nodes. In other words, **whenever the objects are not referenced anymore, they are destroyed and their memory is reclaimed**.

1. your first code is right, when you have internal dependency with other nodes i.e, `tail` node, for example.
2. your second is right, when you doesn't have any dependency with other node.

Comment: thanks, I do not have any tail variable so I guess the second one would be sufficient

Comment: If you had any other local fields that referenced nodes, you could just set those null as well. You *should not* have any references to the node objects outside the List, because that is a huge violation of encapsulation - it defeats the purpose of writing the class in the first place.

Comment: Both ways will work if you have just `head`, or both `head` and `tail`. You can do #2 by just setting `head = null; tail = null;` and it works for the same reason.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel : the violation of encapsulation is out of context here!

Comment: If you are asking a question about which way you should write code, then principles like that cannot be out of context.

Comment: @kaya3: yes that is the same reason i mentioned, when OP have internal dependency to other node, s/he can't claimed memory by simply setting `head=null;`. instead, s/he needs to de-allocate memory by putting `null` to every individual node.

Comment: No, you could just set those other internal dependencies to null (like `tail = null;`) and there is no need to set every individual node's links to `null` as well.

Comment: @KarlKnechtel: i can write my code without following OOPs principle. here the term OOPs is out of context. here OP asked for help about GC's memory claimed terminology.

Comment: @kaya3: you getting me wrong, i am saying if `head` have dependency to other node say `tail`, `category`, even it can have any node in reference, that point you need to destroy all node manually tail, category and all others.

Answer (score 0):

It depends on your implementation.  If your Node class is internal only (so you don't ever return a Node where it might be saved) and you don't hold any in statics, then there should be no path to any node from a garbage collection root and GC will get rid of them.

So it's probably right, unless your implementation is doing something unusual.  (I'm also assuming you don't have a tail variable or anything else that references an internal Node, because those would also need to be set to null).

Comment: yes I do not have any tail variable thanks